# Linking a tKinter Button across classes

Tags: tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-canvas

So I am new to tKinter as well as using classes in python to the degree I am using them here. I have done a lot of research on this topic but I am having a hard time putting it all together. The question is; I have def functions under my main class the first one is def class_Window (Which creates a spread sheet) and the other is def buttons (essentially to hold all my buttons that I create). I am in the process of making a save table button using tkintertable.Tables.TableCanvas save function with makes a pickle file. For the life of me I cannot figure out how to link the button to the table class in the define function.

The errors I get are invalid syntax or has no attribute.

Any assistance on how to get this to come across would be great

```
class AccuracyAssessmentApp:
def __init__(self, parent=Tk()):
    self.mainWindow = (parent)
    self.mainWindow.title("Accuracy Assessment")
    self.mainWindow.geometry("1000x700")
    self.make_txt()
    self.pos_lbl()
    self.buttons()
    self.class_Window()
    self.title_label()


def make_txt(self):
    self.text = Text(self.mainWindow, width = 80, height = 40, background = "#A8A8A8")
    self.text.pack(expand = TRUE, fill = BOTH)


def pos_lbl(self):
    self.pos = Label(self.mainWindow, text = "0,0")
    self.pos.place(x=0, y=0)

    self.pos1 = Label(self.mainWindow, text = "0,350")
    self.pos1.place(x=0, y=350)

    self.pos2 = Label(self.mainWindow, text = "500,0")
    self.pos2.place(x=500, y=0)

def class_Window(self):
    self.tableFrame = Frame()
    self.tableFrame.place(x=680,y=200)
    self.table = TableCanvas(self.tableFrame, rows=30,cols=2, width=240)
    self.table.createTableFrame()

def title_label(self):
    self.titleFrame = Frame(self.mainWindow, bg= '#4A766E', relief="raised", bd=10)
    self.titleFrame.place(x=385, y=20)
    self.title = Label(self.titleFrame, text=("""Accuracy Assessment"""), font=LARGE_FONT, bg= '#4A766E', fg="white", justify="center")
    self.title.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

def buttons(self):
    Button(self.mainWindow, text="Quit", command=self.mainWindow.destroy).place(x=10,y=665)
    Button(self.mainWindow, text="Save", command=self.table.save("AssessmentTable"))
```

This is the error I get:

```
runfile('I:/Custom_Scripts/Personal/AccuracyAssessment/AccuracyAssessment_v2.py', wdir='I:/Custom_Scripts/Personal/AccuracyAssessment')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-d9c198c0cd24>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('I:/Custom_Scripts/Personal/AccuracyAssessment/AccuracyAssessment_v2.py', wdir='I:/Custom_Scripts/Personal/AccuracyAssessment')

  File "C:\Users\jpc08005\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\jpc08005\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 74, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "I:/Custom_Scripts/Personal/AccuracyAssessment/AccuracyAssessment_v2.py", line 79, in <module>
    app = AccuracyAssessmentApp()

  File "I:/Custom_Scripts/Personal/AccuracyAssessment/AccuracyAssessment_v2.py", line 41, in __init__
    self.buttons()

  File "I:/Custom_Scripts/Personal/AccuracyAssessment/AccuracyAssessment_v2.py", line 75, in buttons
    Button(self.mainWindow, text="Save", command=self.table.save("AssessmentTable"))

AttributeError: AccuracyAssessmentApp instance has no attribute 'table'
```

Comment: please show an actual error. The error and traceback has specific information that describes where the problem is, and what the problem is.

Comment: please don't put that in the comments. You can edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
Button(..., command=self.table.save("AssessmentTable"))
```

You are *immediately* calling `self.table.save("AssessmentTable")` at the time the button is created. This is being called before `self.table` has been created. Therefore you get the attribute error.

You need to only call `self.table.save` when the button is clicked. The simplest solution is to create a function that saves the table, and then reference that button in the callback:

```
def save_table(self):
    self.table.save("AssessmentTable")

def buttons(self):
    Button(..., command=self.save_table)
```

Another solution is to use `lambda` or `functools.partial`, though I personally think you should only use those when absolutely need to, and in this case there's no need. Using a separate function adds two lines of code, but makes the code easier to understand and debug.

However, if you want to avoid the use of a separate function you could code it like this:

```
def buttons(self):
    Button(..., command=lambda: self.save_table(self.table.save("AssessmentTable"))
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked perfectly. Still being new to classes this was a great solution to see how it passes through.